# I wonder whether creating a coral shape is possible in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, displacement

Coral
[image: image of a coral]

I have been trying to create this form using Geometry Nodes as I would like to 3d print it and therefore can't use shader displacement. I am quite new to Geometry Nodes and it's all quite foreign to me. How easy is this shape to make?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268712/coral-reef-how-to-blend-scattered-instances/

Comment: I guess, strictly speaking, this is one aspect of differential growth.. e.g. see article [here](https://andylomas.com/extra/andylomas_paper_cellular_forms_aisb50.pdf) (beyond GN)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys!