# GN "Smooth" Solidify

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I've managed to make a smooth solidify:

I attach the file.
[image]

[image]

But how could I do the same on a concave or convex mesh? Like, for example, this deformed half semisphere.I've tried adding the normal to the position and then using a maximum vector math but I couldn't find the solution.
It should look evenly smooth ("the solidified part"), like the 1st example. The deformed original mesh should maintain the same as it was:

[image]
[image]

UPDATE:
I made it work on a curved surface with the following nodes, **but this setup ISN'T VALID for me**, cause I need it to work on a **maxillary surface**. It's for creating a guard, so it maintains the teeth shape on the inside but it's smooth on the outside. (**last image**) I also attach the .blend file:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Could someone help me, please? I know in **3.5** I could use the **blur node** to smooth it but I would like a more efficient solution.

Thank you very much,

Miguel

Comment: Hello, what should it look like when the solidify is applied ?

Comment: Hi, Gorgious. It should look evenly smooth ("the solidified part"), like the 1st example. The deformed original mesh should maintain the same as it was.

Comment: Isn't it enough to just extrude then smooth? [How to eliminate obvious proximity crease intersections?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277590/60486)

Comment: Yeah, but this is quite similar to using 3.5 Blur Attribute Node as I mentioned at the end of the post. But you need many iterations to make it smooth so it's quite computational expensive. There should be another way to do it limiting the extrusion, shouldn't it?