# Vronoi hole pattern from texture

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, shader-nodes, displacement

I want to ad a randomized vronoi style hole pattern for that plan mesh to styalize my headphone stand.

[image: Mesh for the hole]

[image: Taget Value]

Comment: Tissue addon has been suggested for things like this in the past

Comment: @vklidu comes up with a nice way to generate Voronoi meshes  as one of the early steps in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269300/35559). If he's around, maybe can make a version that would suit you.

Comment: So something like that, tissue seems to be very tricky https://www.printables.com/de/model/97992-voronoi-style-pencil-holder