# How to achieve Geospatial Voronoi pattern?

Tags: texturing, shaders, shader-nodes, procedural

I would like to achieve a voronoi pattern like this:
[image]

What I want to do is place a curve and control the size of the voronoi cells using proximity.

Since there is no way to control the size of the cells the way I have described it. I did come up with a work-around which involves the use of multiple voronoi texture nodes with different scales.

[image]

Now, there is a small problem with this setup. You can see that in the ref image, all the cells feel connected. But in the workaround that I have come up with, the next size will be a sudden jump. Now in theory, I could just use more and more voronoi nodes. But that will come with the cost of performance which is something that I want to avoid. Also, that won't completely solve the issue of them not being naturally connected.

Answer (score 5):

Distribute random points with density based on proximity to given geo. Spawn overlapping cones - looking at them from top orthographic view is a cheap way to find intersections:

[image]

Color the cones:

[image]

Result:

[image]

You can animate the bottom radius for an effect like on [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram#Natural_sciences):

[image]

(the cell points visible above is just a happy accident due to camera clipping)

[image]

Set the *Vertices* $ = 4$, for Manhattan distance:

[image]

$3$ and $5$ vertices also look fun…

Answer (score 1):

This one takes a leaf out of [@vklidu's book](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269300/35559), for creating  triangle-cell-based Voronoi geometry.

This version takes as input a plane, and a curve.

- The plane is scaled up and subdivided, to distribute points with variable density
- The density is based on a mapping of proximity to the curve
- A 1-point curve primitive is instanced on the points, and realized
- The scaled plane is converted to a curve, combined with the points, and triangle-filled.
- The Dual is taken of the triangulation
- The whole is Boolean-trimmed with a box created from the input plane.

[image]

Producing this kind of result, in geometry:

[image]

[image]

As @Markus points out in the commentary, this is not a true representation of regions *closest* to  the distributed points, so you would have to watch out for that, if you needed it.

Comment: Awesome. I learned the "fill 0-length curves" trick from vklidu as well. Nice touch to just resample it to 1 point. This is not true Voronoi BTW, but honestly, it looks better than the true Voronoi.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady  Hmm. True,  The Dual is not a distance-function from the vertices, is it. So if you needed minimum-distance-from-points for something else,, it wouldn't work.